# Joining two pandas dataframe with different number of rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframe, df1 and df2. df1 has monthly time index, df2 has quarterly time index. df1 and df2 has different number of rows and columns, I want to:
(1)join them side by side and keep their indexes.
(2) output to excel file.

I have tried pd.concat, but this method concatenate dataframes based on one of the index of the dataframe which I don't want

```
df1:           df2:

   A   B        C  D  E
1  a   b    1   f  s  l
2  c   d    4   k  k  u
            5   y  y  j
```

Expected results in excel:

```
   A   B        C  D  E
1  a   b    1   f  s  l
2  c   d    4   k  k  u
            5   y  y  j
```

Comment: I think you are looking [to insert the columns of df2](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) into df1 perhaps?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? Generally speaking, when we work with tabular data there's a meaning to rows and columns. That is, every column on a row is related to the same entry, and every row in a column shows you the value for each entry. It seems to me that you'd be better off having one sheet for each of those dfs in your excel file (see how here: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_multiple.html)

Comment: Also, you might want to provide an example that matches your description. You mention that you have dataframes with datetime indexes (one quarterly, one monthly), but the example you give uses integer indexes. It'd be easier if you provided example real data (you can change values that might give away sensitive info).

Answer (score 1):

Since `pd.concat` matches the index, you have to reset your index before using the method:

```
pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True), df2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```

---

```
     A    B  C  D  E
0    a    b  f  s  l
1    c    d  k  k  u
2  NaN  NaN  y  y  j
```